# Operations on sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that we have positive sequences $T,S,R$ such that $T\geq S,R$ meaning $T_i\geq S_i$ for every $i$. Let's define a couple of operations $T-S$ and $T+S$ as:
$$(T-S)_k= \inf_{l\geq 0}T_{k+l}-S_l $$
$$(T\sharp S)_k=\max_{k_1+k_2=k}T_{k_1}+S_{k_2}$$
I would like to relate them and i think that $(T-S)\sharp R=(T\sharp R)-S$ but maybe I am wrong.

This is my argument

$$((T-S)\sharp R)_k=\max_{k_1+k_2=k}\inf_{l\geq 0}T_{k_1+l}-S_l+R_{k_2}$$

> interchanging inf with max we got

$=\inf_{l\geq 0}\max_{k_1+k_2=k}T_{k_1+l}-S_l+R_{k_2}=\inf_{l\geq 0}\max_{k_1+k_2=k+l}T_{k_1}+R_{k_2}-S_l=(T\sharp R)-S$

> Obviusly the most suspicious part is the interchanging of inf and max.

I would like to know if there is some restriction to interchange this two operations.

Comment: Well, they are not interchangeable in general. For a sequence $A_n$, $\inf_n\sup_{m\ge n} A_m=\limsup A_n=$ greatest accumulation point of $A_n$, while $\sup_n\inf_{m\ge n}=\liminf A_n=$ smallest accumulation point. They only coincide if $A_n$ is convergent. Though your setting is slightly different.